# airline.vim does not work inside tmux

Tags: vim, tmux, statusline

I am new to tmux and also not an expert on VIM, I tried to use tmux these days, but seems that airline disappeared when I used vim inside tmux. I would like to show you the screen shots and hopefully anyone can help me solve this problem.

[airline in vim](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rf5rC.jpg)

[airline inside tmux](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9Qcs.jpg)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to correctly set `$TERM` environment variable to make vim properly detect 256 colors support by doing the following before opening vim:

```
export TERM=screen-256color
```

Answer (score 3):

While the accepted answer works, it is not cheap. Manually setting the value of the `$TERM` variable will usually be set correctly by itself.

It is usually a good a idea to **force tmux to assume the terminal supports 256 colors.**

In your `~/.bash_aliases`, add:

```
tmux='tmux -2'
```

Answer based on the following posts:

- [What is the difference between screen-256 color and xterm-256color](https://superuser.com/questions/424086/what-is-the-difference-between-screen-256-color-and-xterm-256color#424094)
- [tmux vim colorscheme background is not showing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/167843/tmux-vim-colorscheme-background-is-not-showing?noredirect=1#comment276298_167843)

Answer (score 1):

Add the following line in your `.tmux.conf`

```
set -g default-terminal screen-256color
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, using ubuntu 20.04 inside windows with WSL2, the accepted answer (`export TERM=screen-256color`), just freeze the tmux pane.

The fix for me was add to `~/.vim/vimrc`:

```
set t_Co=256
```